# Can I remove an unmapped status with issues in Jira?

Tags: project-management, jira, agile, scrum, kanban

I have a custom workflow in Jira. I deleted a status with issues, so now it has gone to unmapped status  "Statuses containing issues." When I opened the project's workflow, the deleted status was still there because I think it had an issue. I do not know that issues.

I can not delete the status from unmapped status because it has issues. I tried to change the workflow, but it asked me to assign deleted statues to a new status.

The thing is, I have over 200 bugs that I do not need to track. So adding a current status and then deleting issues step by step is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a work round in place by creating mapping called 'shredder' and perform a bulk-update to map them here. The you can delete them all.